# Is there a possibility to create/save a list of favorite/useful questions?

Tags: support, answered-questions, bookmarks

How can I create/save a list of questions/answers that are useful for me in my account, for later use?

Answer (score 8):

I usually mark the question as a "*favorite*" if I want to be able to have some hope of (more) easily finding it again in the future. (See the image below.)

Another alternative is, of course, to bookmark the post in your browser. I tend to do this less often as I tend to find it more, well, tedious. But I do sometimes also use browser bookmarks, just a lot less often.

---

[image: big, honkin' arrow pointing at the favorites button]

---

#### Some additional suggestions

I also stumbled upon the other options in the list below while I was looking for something else. I decided to mention them here. (If nothing else this might allow me to find them again later. ;-)

1. [**This answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13996/147712) on [*meta stackoverflow*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) also points out that each question has its own RSS feed which you can subscribe to if you wish. I found the RSS link obfuscated at the bottom right hand corner of the page. (See also the image below.)

   [image: big, honkin' arrow pointing at link to RSS feed]

   This option is apparently not restricted to question pages. Many other pages on the [*Stack Exchange*](http://stackexchange.com) sites also appear to have RSS feeds available.
2. [**This answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86250/147712) (to the same question) provides a reference to an App on the [*StackApps*](https://stackapps.com/) site which might be useful. 

   Note: I have not used any App from StackApps yet, so I have no idea if this is a good tool or not.
3. [**This answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95519/147712) appears to provide a good explanation of how to use your profile dropdown at the top of each page to sleuth out updates to your "*Favorites*" list.

Answer (score 1):

I use favorites and I also use my user profile.  That way I can select a few questions and organization them as I like.  I like to keep a few questions handy for reference or later implementation, to have them handy to recommend to other users, and to remind myself to vote for them (after the vote bucket is refilled).  I do that in my profile, because my favorites list is too large and unwieldy.  Also, if anyone checks my profile, they will see questions I think are interesting or important, and may read them or vote for good/bad answers there.

Comment: I looked at your profile. What I think you were saying is that you save the links to some questions (or answers?) you want to focus on for some reason by adding these links to the `About Me` section of your profile. Is that correct?

Comment: Hmm. Yes.  So my 'about me' is really a bunch of links.