# How to follow a question (with Stack Exchange emails)?

Tags: support, email

If I add a comment or an answer to a question, Stack Exchange sends me an email when someone adds a further comment or answer. That is tremendously useful.

But sometimes I see a question to which I do not know the answer, and I would like to follow the question.

How do I get Stack Exchange to send me email updates when someone posts a comment or answer to such a question? (At the moment, I create a link and have to remember to visit the link regularly.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the preferences screen in your user account you can enable this:

[image]

To subscribe to a question click the star underneath the voting arrows.

See also:

- [Is there a possibility to create/save a list of favorite/useful questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3082/is-there-a-possibility-to-create-save-a-list-of-favorite-useful-questions)