# Is there a way to subscribe to a Q&A and get notified of _all_ activity (in the StackExchange Inbox)?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

From other online "forums" (e.g. http://forums.mozillazine.org/ which is "powered by" https://www.phpbb.com/) I'm used to having a feature to **subscribe to a thread**.

I realize that here you can use things like @username to notify someone (at least in a comments thread).

Is there (currently) a straightforward way of subscribing to a Q&A and getting notifications of ***all*** activity (in the StackExchange Inbox)? If not, where would be a good place to request it, kindly?

((pretty sure this question *could* be a duplicate... plz advise, if so.))

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime(as a workaround) you can hit the "Favorite Star"

Which is here:

[image] [image]

This will update you on changes of a question in your profile page.

To see the changes:

[image]

Click "Favorites" notice the "1" which tells me one of my favorites has changed, then click on "Activity" and the highlighted questions will be the ones that have recently changed.

Comment: This won't get it "too your inbox", but it does the trick.

Comment: it used to go into your inbox, or maybe I just want that feature enough I'm changing my memories, which is also possible.

Comment: a bit counter-intuitive, as I wouldn't describe all Q&A's I'd like to track for a while as "favourite" Q&A's - though I have *some* favourites out there... anyway, thx for that info; I'll leave the question open for a bit, as this seems more like a work-around making do with what's available *now* than what might be worthwhile implementing in askubuntu/stackexchange in the future... IMHO... :-)

Comment: @jrg yep looks like a change broke that, and now it is really hard to see *what* has changed for favorites - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes

Comment: Check this out, looks like subscribing to an rss feed of the question may work, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3082/is-there-a-possibility-to-create-save-a-list-of-favorite-useful-questions